# Automated referencing: a code chunk's line number in R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, xelatex

In an rmd file have a code chunk that currently begins at line 50. However that may change as I edit the document. In the R markdown document's text, I'd like to reference the line number of that particular code chunk. Does R markdown have the capability to reference line numbers for a particular segment of code?

````
Line 50    ```{r wrapper, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
library(padr)
Code goes here...
```
````

In the Rmd text:

In (*insert Line 50*) the rmd file begins the `wrapper` code chunk.

Comment: I see a possibility here using JS when producing HTML documents. For PDF's I would say no chance of doing this.